# Firestore rule auth doesn't seems working

Tags: javascript, firebase, react-native, google-cloud-firestore

I have configured the firestore rules like below:

```
service cloud.firestore {
  match /databases/{database}/documents {
    match /bills/{billid} {
      allow create: if request.auth.uid != null;
    }
  }
}
```

I add a record like below:

```
import firebase from 'react-native-firebase';

const db = firebase.firestore().collection('bills');

const data = {
        year: year,
        month: month,
        description: description,
        dateCreated: new Date()    
};

db.add(data).then(ref => {
       console.log('added record with id: ', ref.id);
}).catch(error => {
       console.error("Error adding record: ", error);
});
```

However, the record still get into firestore database where it should not since I have set the rule

**allow create: if request.auth.uid != null;**

Did I set the rules wrongly?

Comment: What exactly is `db` here?

Comment: And where are you running this code?  In the client web app or with the admin SDK?

Comment: updated with the code

Comment: I am running in react native

Comment: Why isn't the data supposed to be making it into the database? Are you saying that you're running this code while no user is logged in, and it still creates a document?  Please be absolutely sure that there is no current user.